# How to schedule random message on localNotification

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

how to schedule random message for localNotification.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self scheduleDailyLocalNotification];
    }


-(void)scheduleDailyLocalNotification{

    UNMutableNotificationContent *localNotification = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
        localNotification.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@“Title!” arguments:nil];
srand(time(NULL));
int r = rand() % 6;
localNotification.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:[self.notificationMessages objectAtIndex:r] arguments:nil];            
        localNotification.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
        UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 24  repeats:YES];

        //    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"Time for a run!" content:localNotification trigger:trigger];

        NSString *identifier = @"LOCALNOTIFICATION";
        UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier
                                                                              content:localNotification trigger:trigger];

        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            NSLog(@"NOTIFICATION CREATED");
        }];
 }
```

Its shows same message again and again!

Comment: i think you need to make the array of string in which you store messages get the random number between o to your array count and put the message which is coming on that random number index

Comment: @chiragshah I use the random its show message same again and again!

Comment: Use NSTImer to trigger local notification dont  use NotificationRequest to handle time interval then you can show random messages

Comment: The code you have provided clearly shows that you are registering only one message body and triggering it again and again

Comment: @kiran how many message you have?

Comment: @chiragshah only 7 message I have,  I want to show randomly each message every day completed.

Comment: @MuhammedIrfan . I need not to use NSTimer

Comment: @kiran then there is one other approach like start displaying massage from index zero after every notification send increase that count by that way you get random message

Comment: How can that achive is my question!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to repeat this notification again and again set the repeats interval *NO*

```
UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 24  repeats:NO];
```

Comment: In that case notification will trigger only once.  Not for another day

Comment: @kiran I think you are missing something. You have to schedule multiple notifications for multiple days with different titles. You can not achieve different titles with the same scheduled notification. If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: you are correct!  It’s schedules trigger same message on given period of time.  I am wondering about random message how it works here.

Comment: What the minimum time interval for your notification? If it is more then one day, You can keep scheduled DateTime in userInfo of Notification and whenever App comes in foreground check scheduled DateTime from fired date of this notification, If fire date is greater then scheduled DateTime, then cancel this notification and set another notification with a random title. I know it is tricky and hard but you can do. But if the user does not come foreground more than one day he will get same notification :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this

```
    var index = 0

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            [super viewDidLoad];
            [self scheduleDailyLocalNotification];
        }


    -(void)scheduleDailyLocalNotification{

        UNMutableNotificationContent *localNotification = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
            localNotification.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@“Title!” arguments:nil];
    srand(time(NULL));
    localNotification.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:[self.notificationMessages objectAtIndex:index] arguments:nil];  
        if index < self.notificationMessage.count{
             index += 1
        }else{
             index = 0
         }      
            localNotification.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
            UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 24  repeats:YES];

            //    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"Time for a run!" content:localNotification trigger:trigger];

            NSString *identifier = @"LOCALNOTIFICATION";
            UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier
                                                                                  content:localNotification trigger:trigger];

            UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
            center.delegate = self;
            [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                NSLog(@"NOTIFICATION CREATED");
            }];
     }
```

Comment: Still its showing same single message again and again!

Comment: @kiran it is showing same massage because you put local notification on repeat mode

Comment: In that case notification trigger only once.

Comment: @kiran if you want to trigger same notification with random message then it is not possible